# iMac - No sound with internal speakers

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, mac

I'm facing a really strange issue that has existed on various versions of Mint(from 17.x to 18.2) and even on Ubuntu 18.04 currently. I have an iMac 21.5 running 18.04 with Kernel 4.16.12 with the following Audio Device settings.
[Audio Device Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NX9OQ.png)

[Here are the details of the machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUmc7.png)

The issue is that in-spite of "Speakers - Built in Audio" being selected as the default device, I don't hear any sound coming out of the iMac speakers most of the time. It works sometimes. Chrome seems to be having this issue more often than Firefox or any other media software. When it doesn't work, looks like the sound goes through to HDMI - Display Port 3.

Can someone please help me in how to make sure the default option of "Speakers - Built in Speakers" can be made to 'stick'?

Here are the outputs of [**aplay -l**](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/dz6X7KSJph/) and [**pacmd list-cards**](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/6RvF3PPy5v/).

Comment: from your system information, HDMI audio would appear to be set as default device 0. Do you ever use HDMI for audio playback? simplest solution is turn off HDMI audio in Pulseaudio if you don't need it

Comment: Hi. THanks for the response. Nope don't use HDMI at all. Should I install pavucontrol to disable it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://askubuntu.com/q/1464550/124466

Answer (score 0):

You can stop Pulseaudio using HDMI in pavucontrol. 
got to Configuration tab and change profile setting to 'Off'

You can also do this with terminal command -`pactl set-card-profile 0 off`

I would recommend installing pavucontrol, it is best tool for checking and adjusting Pulseaudio settings. Although most Linux versions have a panel control, none that I know of show all the settings, and some do not save settings changes correctly

Comment: I did turn off HDMI in pavucontrol as you said and it no longer shows in the Ubuntu Sound Panel too, but the issue manifests differently now. When I restart the machine, and say open Kodi, it plays sound perfectly. Now when I close Kodi, and then open a browser and play something in Youtube, it fails to play sound. Out of curiosity , I ran this during the issue and see that the device is busy.            
 **aplay -D plughw:1,0 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Left.wav
aplay: main:788: audio open error: Device or resource busy** . When a wait a few mins and run above command, things work fine.

Comment: is your kodi audio set to use Pulseaudio or ALSA? Does pavucontrol show youtube audio playing even if you can't hear it? Does youtube video play OK? If pavucontrol shows audio playback streams, Pulseaudio will be using audio device so direct alsa playback with 'aplay' would fail until these are cleared. Try command 'paplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Left.wav'

Comment: Kodi is setup to use Pulse default device. Yes, when I play a youtube video with Chrome and I hear no sound, pavucontrol does show Chrome playback tracking the sound , but I don't hear anything from the speaker. I tried playing a YT video in Firefox and Chrome simultaneously, and also tried the paplay command from above. All of them appear on the Pulse playback, but no sound from the speakers

Comment: Strange thing is, when I try Kodi, the speakers start playing audio. Then when I go back to Chrome,it doesn't work, but Firefox works. During all these issues, pavucontrol shows the streams playing

Comment: if sound looks to be playing normally in pavucontrol Playback tab. 
check levels and mute buttons in Output Devices tab next. make sure 'show' option at bottom of each tab is set so stuff isn't hidden.
if that all looks ok, check in alsamixer that levels are ok and not muted. keep alsamixer and pavucontrol visible and try to spot any changes when audio is working and not

Answer (score 0):

3 Weeks Ago#3arcusm arcusm is offline
First Cup of Ubuntu

Join Date
Feb 2023
Beans
2
Re: No sound on iMac
I was having the same problem on my iMac. I stumbled upon this possible solution. Says it's for Macbook Pro but it seems a lot of Macs use the same (or similar) Cirrus chipset for sound. I followed the instructions on my iMac and it worked perfectly. Sound card recognized and I get sound from the interanl speakers.

https://github.com/davidjo/snd_hda_macbookpro

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).