# I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on an iMac 5k 2019 and cannot get the sound to play from the inbuilt speakers

Tags: drivers, soundcard

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on an iMac 5k 2019 and cannot get the sound to play from the inbuilt speakers. My sound card is an Intel Cannon Lake.

Output from `lspci -knn | grep Audio` :

```
Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS [8086:a348] (rev 10)
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere HDMI Audio [Radeon RX 470/480 / 570/580/590] [1002:aaf0]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere HDMI Audio [Radeon RX 470/480 / 570/580/590] [1002:aaf0]
```

The second card is the AMD HDMI one, and it works fine when connected.

I have played around and tried reinstalling PulseAudo and Alsamixer following instructions like these.

I have updated the kernel to the latest mainline version from Canonical which at the time of writing is 5.9 in the hope that newer drivers would fix the issue, but so far I no luck.

This seems like a common problem. Does anyone have any more information and hopefully has a fix for this?

Comment: Try running the latest version, Ubuntu 23.04. Newer versions of Ubuntu have better support for relatively recent hardware.

Comment: Also try this https://askubuntu.com/q/1184634/124466

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/no-sound-on-imac-5k-imac-19-1-27-2019/111631/15?u=archisman) on the Manjaro forum to get the sound output working. The mic input still does not seem to work.

First, update your system, and install linux-headers.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade -y
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

Install `git` and `build-essential`, in case they are already not installed.

```
sudo apt install git build-essential
```

Now, clone the github repo.

```
git clone https://github.com/egorenar/snd-hda-codec-cs8409.git
```

Compile it.

```
cd snd-hda-codec-cs8409
make
```

Finally, install it, and **reboot**.

```
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instruction above but still no sound.
Appreciate your guidance to get this fixed.

Please let me know what information required so you could help me.

Thank you.